# What does "w.r.t. " mean in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, type-systems

This word shows up many times in this web page : https://kotlinlang.org/spec/type-system.html#function-types

Can anyone help me to find out where defines this word?

Comment: [with reference to](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/wrt) although this usage looks more like "with respect to"

Comment: It can also be short for "with regard to". It's generally used to connect what you're talking about with something else - defining a relationship, the context or topic, etc.

Comment: In case it's not clear: this isn't about Kotlin. The abbreviation has no special meaning in Kotlin (or, as far as I know, in any programming language) — it's general written English.

Comment: Thanks all, @gidds I thought it has special meaning. I got the "with respect to" from translator but I didn't accept it.... I thought there is a certain "type system" called "w.r.t".

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13809/what-does-wrt-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WRT means with reference to.. it seems that alot is used in abbreviation